# UPNP - How to configure GUFW

Tags: firewall, upnp

I have a TP-LINK TD-W8968 router with a mediaserver (UPNP/DLNA) port. The port has a USB stick with media content. I can access this content via XBMC and Totem/Movie player without any hassle. But only when the GUFW firewall is disabled.

I'd rather not have to disable my firewall every time I want to access this shared content. However, I don't know how to configure the firewall.

I tried adding a rule with what I thought might be the address of the USB stick, but GUFW wouldn't accept my best guess. The addresses I tried were 192.168.1.1/MediaShare/ and 192.168.1.1/volume/VIDEO/. I have no doubt that I'm doing this all wrong.

Can anyone help point me and my PC in the right direction?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The GUFW firewall solution (for me) was:

IN (FROM) Port 1900:1901

IN (TO) Port Empty

OUT (FROM) Port Empty

OUT (TO) Port 1900:1901

Both using UDP

[How to add UPNP to Rhythmbox & Totem / Movie Player](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/240-ubuntu-precise-upnp-dlna-client)